# Python : Runtime Warning : Overflow encountered in square, add, multiply, substract

Tags: python, runtime-error, overflow

I'm beginning with Python so I might be asking a not so subtle question, but after quite a lot of research I couldn't resolve this error.
I'm actually trying to solve a physics problem using the Gray-Scott model, but I'm stuck at the very end of the code :  the results are not considered as numbers and there's an overflow encountered in square, add, multiply and substract.

Anyone here have the slightest idea of where this comes from ?

Thanks !

These are the initial conditions of the problem I'm trying to solve :

```
n = 192
Du, Dv, F, k = 0.00016, 0.00008, 0.035, 0.065 
dh = 5/(n-1)  
T = 8000
dt = .9 * dh**2 / (4*max(Du,Dv))
nt = int(T/dt)

uvinitial = numpy.load('./uvinitial.npz')

Uin = uvinitial['U']
Vin = uvinitial['V']
```

Now here are my functions :

```
def Nd1(U,V) :
    return - U*(V)**2 + F*(1-U)


def Nd2(U,V) :
    return U*(V)**2 -(F+k)*V


def gray_scott_solve(Du, Dv, dh, dt, nt, Uin, Vin, Nd1, Nd2):

    Uplus = Uin.copy()
    Vplus = Vin.copy()

    for n in range(nt):

        U = Uplus.copy()  
        V = Vplus.copy()

        Uplus[1:-1,1:-1] = ( Nd1(U[1:-1,1:-1], V[1:-1,1:-1]) + Du/(dh**2) \
                            *(U[2:,1:-1] + U[:-2,1:-1] - 4*U[1:-1,1:-1]) \
                            + U[1:-1,2:] + U[1:-1,:-2] )*dt \
                            + U[1:-1,1:-1]

        Uplus[:,-1] = Uplus[:,-2]    
        Uplus[-1,:] = Uplus[-2,:]
        Uplus[:,0] = Uplus[:,1]
        Uplus[0,:] = Uplus[1,:]

        Vplus[1:-1,1:-1] = ( Nd2(U[1:-1,1:-1], V[1:-1,1:-1]) + Du/(dh**2) \
                            *(V[2:,1:-1] + V[:-2,1:-1] - 4*V[1:-1,1:-1]) \
                            + V[1:-1,2:] + V[1:-1,:-2] )*dt \
                            + V[1:-1,1:-1]

        Vplus[:,-1] = Vplus[:,-2]
        Vplus[-1,:] = Vplus[-2,:]
        Vplus[:,0]= Vplus[:,1]
        Vplus[0,:]= Vplus[1,:]


    return U, V
```

I now want to print the results I'm looking for :

```
U, V = gray_scott_solve(Du, Dv, dh, dt, nt, Uin, Vin, Nd1, Nd2)

print(U[100,::40])
```

And I finally get this error :

```
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]

C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:5: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:5: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:11: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:18: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:18: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
C:\Users\Anto\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:18: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the method of lines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_lines) to approximate the PDEs as a systems of ODEs, and then using Euler's method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) to solve the ODEs.  Are you sure that your choice of `dt` is small enough to ensure that Euler's method is stable?

Comment: Well I didn't know it was called the Method of lines but yes, this is what I am trying to do.
I indeed got rid of the error message with a smaller `dt`, but unfortunately my teacher (I'm a physics student) wants me to find answers with this specific dt. I'll continue searching and maybe try a less unstable method, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it written, your spatial step, `dh`, will be equal to zero in python 2:

```
n  = 192
...
dh = 5 / ( n - 1 )
```

If you are using python 3 then dh will properly be treated as a float.

Otherwise, as was stated by @WarrenWeckesser, you are using the Method of lines and integrating in time with the Forward Euler method, which with your set of constraints (you said that your instructor specified your timestep and other parameter values) is apparently unstable. However, using a Runge Kutta Two method will work for your `dt` (I verified this), but your instructor may have mentioned the time integration that you should use.

Regardless, if Runge Kutta Two seems daunting, use a second order central space method:

```
u_{n+1} = u_{n-1} + 2 * dt * f(t_n,u_n)
```

where `f(t,u)` is the right hand side and `u_{n-1}` is the value of `u` at time `t_{n-1}`, or the backward euler method.

Comment: I will try both the methods you suggested, it is not what my instructor is expecting but he will understand, if manage to have good results this way. And will be very good practice for me ! Thank you very much for your help.